# Can we move this question to Programmers.Stackexhange?

Tags: support, migration, closed-questions, close-reasons

Can we move [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371515/version-control-strategy-for-a-budding-programmer) to [Programmers.Stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)? I still think it is a relevant question that is useful to many budding programmers. A few people even seem to agree with me!

Comment: Flagging the post might have been a better choice over posting the request here...

Comment: @Lix: Thanks for point out flagging. I was not aware of that option.

Comment: ChrisF is a ♦mod over on PSE... I think you should take his advice...

Answer (score 11):

No.

There are already several questions along the same lines on the site. Including, but not limited to:

[Version control for independent developers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27147/version-control-for-independent-developers)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/which-version-control-system-a-net-vb6-developer-in-a-small-team-should-use

[version control for small team](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31558/version-control-for-small-team)

One of these (or a related question) will probably have the same information in it.

If you can't find a question that covers the same areas as yours then we can look at migrating it, but I'd be surprised if you don't find one.

Comment: Not really. If you read my question and the referenced questions closely, my question is different. You will notice that I am asking about version control strategies and policy, rather than whether to use it or what to use. I am asking how effective programmers use it? What is their strategy?

Comment: @haziz - these were the first questions I found on a quick search. If you do a more intensive search you might find something more relevant.